# Python Tkinter OSError: [WinError 123] browse directory cancellation

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using askdirectory to browse for a folder path.

```
def select_folder():
   filename = askdirectory(initialdir="~")
   target_folder.set(filename)
   os.chdir(filename)
   print (os.getcwd())
```

This works fine, until I cancel the "Browse for folder window" without selecting a directory.
If I cancel the browse window without selecting a directory, an OSError is thrown.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\ImageRenamer.py", line 9, in select_folder os.chdir(filename)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ''
```

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: `if not filename: return`?

Comment: Thanks, so simple!

Comment: `if filename:`  run those instructions `else:` run appropriate action.